# Amending a text file in Sharepoint via Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, text, sharepoint

I have an Excel spreadsheet on a Sharepoint site that I would like to keep as read-only. However, my users will occasionally need to add small amounts of data, which I thought could be best stored in a small text file. I can read the text data into the Excel userform easily enough, and I can amend the text file with new data equally easy - but only if I have already checked the text file out. This doesn't work for other users of course. Is there some method of *checking out* a file - which isn't a workbook - out via Excel VBA, or will I have to switch to storing the updateable data in another workbook?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use VBA to read textfiles. You can use this example for instance: https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/read-data-from-text-file.html where you can read the data per line.